# Wrong calculation result on uint64_t

Tags: c, linux, math, 64-bit

### Context

Debian 64bits.

I have this code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    uint64_t b = 5000000000;/* 5 000 000 000 */
    uint64_t a = (b*b)/2;

    printf("a = %llu\n",a);

return 0;
}
```

### Problem

Javascript, my hand calculator and the virtual calculator in my operating system give me a result of 1.25×10^19 whereas my c program above gives  a = 3276627963145224192

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't the result will be `1.25 * 10^19`??

Comment: Nice you are right I missed a zero :)

Comment: Well that one zero can make the result to overflow... :-)

Comment: `5000000000 > 2^32`, so `5000000000^2 > 2^64`, that's simple to see the overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intermediate operation of `b*b` has value which is greater than what a 64-bit register can hold, hence it overflows.

Since, `b (= 5 000 000 000) > 2^32`, hence, `b*b > 2^64`

And, since `5000000000 * 5000000000 / 2` can never fit into 64-bit variable, you cannot calculate this value in C without using special methods like representing number using arrays.

Also, as @Joachim Pileborg suggested, you should assign `unsigned long long` value to `b` as

`uint64_t b = 5000000000ull;`

Answer (score 1):

`uint64_t` can't hold the result of `b*b`.

The result of `b*b` is 25000000000000000000. That is 25x10^18.

But `uint64_t` can hold maximum value upto 6553255926290448384. Hence overflow occurs in `b*b` operation.

Due to this overflow you are not getting the actual result!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    uint64_t b = 5000000000LL;/* 5 000 000 000 */
    uint64_t a = (((uint64_t)b)*b)/2LL;

    printf("a = %llu\n",a);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just providing code without any explanation isn't very helpful.

Comment: That `(uint64_t)b` cast is unnecessary. Also, it still gives the incorrect result OP mentions.